# How to translate nested CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a stored procedure that was not written by me. 
Could you please help me translate `CASE` statement in `WHERE` clause?

```
   --Declaring the parameter for SP
DECLARE
        @CompanyGuids varchar(8000) = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02'
--Declaring table variable that will contain only CompanyGuid 
DECLARE @CompanyGuidsTbl TABLE(Guid uniqueidentifier)
    IF @CompanyGuids IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @CompanyGuidsTbl
        SELECT DISTINCT CompanyGuid FROM  tblCompanies 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @CompanyGuidsTbl
        SELECT * FROM dbo.StringOfGuidsToTable(@CompanyGuids,',')
    END
--Select statement
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM    MyTable1 INNER JOIN MyTable2
 /*  this is where I am confused  */
WHERE   
        CASE WHEN @CompanyGuids IS NOT NULL
        THEN   
        CASE WHEN tblCompanies.CompanyGuid in (SELECT Guid FROM @CompanyGuidsTbl)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE 1
        END = 1
```

Correct me if I'm wrong:

```
  "So if the parameter @CompanyGuids is NOT NULL, then we are checking if table @CompanyGuidsTbl has assigned parameter and if it does - then we gonna use it, but if it does not - ??? "
```

Maybe there is a way to rewrite it?
Thanks

Comment: ...somebody was likely trying to avoid needing dynamic sql, but unless they took certain steps that's likely to backfire (and may have hurt performance anyways).  What's more bizarre is that they're dumping _all_ ids into a temp table, which means they could have just performed a `JOIN` anyways, instead of the wacky case logic (granted, having a statement without the check would have performed better).  Although unless`StringOfGuidsToTable` returns distinct results, a `JOIN` isn't guaranteed to return the same results.

Comment: The WHERE condition, as you've written it, should throw an error, because tblCompanies is not part of your query and it's not syntactically correct, but even if it were it makes no sense to me unless there's more to the query you haven't shown...

Comment: I think what the person who wrote it was trying to do was say "If `@CompanyGuids` IS NULL, select everything, otherwise check whether the GUIDs in `@CompanyGuidsTbl` are in tblCompanies" but that requires either tblCompanies or `@CompanyGuidsTbl` to be in the final query, which they are not...? Or it's trying to check whether all GUIDs in the `@CompanyGuids` string are in tblCompanies and only show results if this is true? Or that at least one is? Hard to tell which it is without seeing the actual query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A poorly constructed statement for sure, but yes it is ultimately checking a truth statement where 1 = 1. First checks for an empty variable, then if the variable is not empty it checks if the CompanyGUID in tblCompanies is in the list supplied in the variable, returning 1 if it is found (thus 1 = 1 is true so the record is matched), or if it is not found (in which case 0 = 1, which is false so the record is not matched). Awful stuff!

Comment: Agreed this is really poorly done. Obfuscation of logic is not a badge of coding skills.